# Turn-based multiplayer game (Game Center, iOS) - Dismiss GKMatchmakerViewController and presenting own user interface to play a turn

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, multiplayer

I am implementing a turn-based multiplayer game with game center. The first view controller (ViewController) shows the menu and it is already possible to display the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` on button tap. After inviting a friend for the game, the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` disappears and game center 'starts' the game. The problem is that the game does not really start because it belongs to another view controller (`SecondViewController`). I am not able to use segues because I do not know how to assign a segue identifier to the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` (because it is not in Storyboard). I know that there has to be a possibility to realize it because many apps use this feature. The Apple Developer Documentation solves this problem using a custom segue, but how is this possible? Any ideas?

Apple Developer Documentation:

'Typically, your game dismisses the matchmaker view controller and immediately starts its own user interface to allow the player to play a turn.' >> That's what I want to do!

```
-(void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GamePlayScene"])
    {
        MyGamePlayViewController* gameVC = (MyGamePlayViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
        gameVC.delegate = self;
        gameVC.match = (GKTurnBasedMatch*) sender;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two "View Controller"(Scene) in "Main.storyboard". One for all the "game center stuff"(Default:GameViewController), another for "game logic"(MyGamePlayViewController). After that hold "ctrl" key and drag the first scene to the other and select "present modally".
See bild.
[image]

Take care of the arrows, there you have to set your "identifier".

Hope this will help. Good luck.